# How do I pass values through xaml properties into custom ContentView viewmodel

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to pass values through properties on a custom content view that I have made. I wanted to have a parent page that is able to declare instances of the custom view, and pass in an ID if needed. I want the ID to be received by the custom view, which should then set the property in the view's view model. Currently my attempts have been unsuccessful, it seems the view model never gets its ID updated. Every time I run it the ID that is shown in the label is an empty guid.

[image: Labels with correct and incorrect Guids]

I have the following four classes defined in the project:

My actual application that creates the main page: **`App`**

**C#** (App.xaml.cs)

```cs
using ExampleDataBinding.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ExampleDataBinding
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new TestMainPage();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The main page that is shown in my App: **`TestMainPage`**

**XAML** (`TestMainPage.xaml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ExampleDataBinding.Views" 
             x:Class="ExampleDataBinding.Views.TestMainPage"
             x:DataType="views:TestMainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding MainPageID}" />
            <views:TestContentView ArbitraryGuid="{Binding MainPageID}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**C#** (`TestMainPage.xaml.cs`)

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ExampleDataBinding.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TestMainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private Guid mainPageID = Guid.NewGuid();
        public Guid MainPageID
        {
            get => mainPageID;
            set => mainPageID = value;
        }

        public TestMainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

    }
}
```

The view that the main page is trying to load: **`TestContentView`**

**XAML** (`TestContentView.xaml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:ExampleDataBinding.ViewModels"
             x:Class="ExampleDataBinding.Views.TestContentView"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:TestContentViewModel">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Label Text="{Binding Guid}" />
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**C#** (`TestContentView.xaml.cs`)

```cs
using ExampleDataBinding.ViewModels;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ExampleDataBinding.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TestContentView : ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty ArbitraryGuidProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ArbitraryGuid),
                                                                                                typeof(Guid?),
                                                                                                typeof(TestContentView),
                                                                                                null,
                                                                                                BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                                                                                propertyChanged: ArbitraryGuidPropertyChanged);

        private static void ArbitraryGuidPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var currentTestContentView = bindable as TestContentView;
            currentTestContentView.UpdateViewModelGuid();
        }

        private void UpdateViewModelGuid()
        {
            if(ArbitraryGuid.HasValue)
                viewModel.Guid = ArbitraryGuid.Value;
        }

        public Guid? ArbitraryGuid
        {
            get => (Guid?)GetValue(ArbitraryGuidProperty);
            set => SetValue(ArbitraryGuidProperty, value);
        }

        private TestContentViewModel viewModel;

        public TestContentView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = viewModel = new TestContentViewModel();
        }

    }
}
```

The view model for the `TestContentView`: **`TestContentViewModel`**

**C#** (`TestContentViewModel.cs`)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ExampleDataBinding.ViewModels
{
    public class TestContentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Guid guid = Guid.Empty;
        public Guid Guid
        {
            get => guid;
            set => SetProperty(ref guid, value);
        }

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
                                        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "",
                                        Action onChanged = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
                return false;

            backingStore = value;
            onChanged?.Invoke();
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed == null)
                return;

            changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I thought I should be able to have my `TestMainPage` create a `TestContentView` and pass in the arbitrary value through the Xaml parameter, but I'm confused as to how it is actually working.

I would like to keep the `TestContentView` using its own viewmodel that gets populated from a binding or property value if possible.

I may be going in the complete wrong direction here, so any advice is welcome. Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Is there a way to just set a property in XAML without having it bind? I thought I was creating an instance of the `TestContentView` in the XAML of the `TestMainPage` and thought I was having it set the property there. I originally tried going the route of a constructor, but wasn't sure how I should pass `Guid` types in XAML. That does sound like the correct approach though.

The only thing I left out from this example is the `App` class, which instantiates the `TestMainPage`; I'll add that in an update.

Answer (score 0):

TestMainPage doesn't set BindingContext.
So `{Binding MainPageID}` doesn't connect to anything.
In TestMainPage.xaml.cs:

```cs
public TestMainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = this;
}
```

---

OR If you add a ViewModel to TestMainPage, then move MainPageID to that VM. And set BindingContext to the VM.

Comment: I added that line, and set my `TestMainPage` Content to now have a `StackLayout` with a `Label` that has the ID. Even with the binding context change it is still showing an empty guid at the end. I've updated my question with the code.

Comment: Good - you’ve made progress - you see it in first label. Now, Debug with breakpoints and stepping through code. Does UpdateViewModelGuid run? When it does, does ArbitraryGuid have a value? This is the kind of debugging *you* need to do, whenever a problem occurs. Find out **exactly** where something doesn't behave as expected.

Comment: Ah sorry, I should've included that in the post. I have breakpoints in `ArbitraryGuidPropertyChanged` and `UpdateViewModelGuid` neither of them have been getting hit. It's actually the reason I posted the question in the first place. I have tried so many things to get this to work. 

I would expect `ArbitraryGuid` to be set in the XAML when `<views:TestContentView ArbitraryGuid="{Binding MainPageID}"/>` is called, but it doesn't seem to ever call a setter on `ArbitraryGuid` either.

Comment: ok. I think xaml isn’t binding correctly to `Guid?` property. Change it to `Guid`, see if that works. Then use all-zeroes Guid to represent none.

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it gave me the same results. I managed to do it all in code-behind, instead of the XAML, since I only need to set the value once. I think I need to go read the documentation on data binding again and see if I can make more sense of it 

Comment: Glad you got it to work. Your code and xaml looked good to me. Must be some subtle detail. I have run into problems with other value types, such as enums, not working correctly. Could **pass around a string** - that would be reliable. What I don’t like about xaml and binding is when something goes wrong, it’s impossible to trace the problem. If we could just watch xamarin go through the steps, see why it doesn’t transfer the value… ah well.

Comment: I think I know how to make it reliable. Explicit use of an IValueConverter, to convert between the property value and the string to display. I bet xamarin fails to convert from the string representation back to a Guid. Converter’s ConvertBack could fix that.

Comment: The purpose of this example project was because I wanted to implement it on a larger scale in another project. I'll have to try the `IValueConverter` and pass a string around. I totally agree, xaml makes it much harder to figure out what's going on when things aren't working perfectly.

Comment: It seems I get the same results when using the `IValueConverter`. I'm going to stick to code-behind here because it's much more clear to me what's actually happening. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you add to question the version you did using IValueConverter? Show the converter, and how you used it. When I get time, I'll attempt to figure out why that doesn't work - that's important functionality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245275/discussion-between-ibrennan208-and-toolmakersteve).